# second return value from first function is printing twice

Tags: python, function, return

I am attempting to simply print out the values(ports) that I have appended to their respective lists. I am separating this by tcp and udp. My dictionary that I am passing to `_does_port_dict_have_type` looks like this `{'22': 'TCP', '53': 'UDP', '31337': 'TCP', '80': 'TCP', '515': 'UDP'}`

Here is my code

```
x = _expected_ports_type_to_dict(ET.parse('scanme.nmap.org.xml'))


TCP_LIST = []
UDP_LIST = []


def _does_port_dict_have_type(port_dict):
    for port, typee in port_dict.iteritems():
         if (typee is not None) and len(typee) > 0:
             if typee == "TCP":
                 TCP_LIST.append(port)
             else:
                 UDP_LIST.append(port)
        else:
            pass
    return ','.join(UDP_LIST), ','.join(TCP_LIST)


UDP = _does_port_dict_have_type(x)[0]
TCP = _does_port_dict_have_type(x)[1]


def print_value(func):
    print func


print_value(UDP)
print_value(TCP)
```

Here is my output `80,31337,22      515,53,515,53`

The TCP variable or the [1] position of _does_port_dict_have_type() is the value that always shows up twice. It doesn't matter if I pass it UDP_LIST or TCP_LIST. Does anyone have any ideas to why this may be happening?

Comment: ahhhhhh. the array is being appended to twice since the function is being ran twice when I call print_value for the second time. correct?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem :)

Comment: Yes, because you're creating TCP_LIST and UDP_LIST outside of the function, hence their contents are being preserved between function calls.

Comment: This is why you should not use global variables, but instead program pure functions, whenever possible

Comment: BTW you can simplify some of your logic, your `if` conditions are unnecessarily complex.

Comment: @UCProgrammer good job of catching that yourself there! ;)

Comment: @davidzemens thanks!

Comment: @graipher will do!

Comment: @davidzemens how could it be improved?

Comment: This test seems totally unnecessary: `if (typee is not None) and len(typee) > 0:`. If you change the nested `esle` to an `elif (typee == "UDP")` that will cover all the scenarios properly.

Comment: And you could use comprehension instead of iteration, python-3 code: `TCP_LIST = list([k for k,v in port_dict.items() if v == "TCP"])`.

Comment: @DavidZemens Possibly. I was thinking the same. I'm working off my coworkers code and tweaking a few things. The codebase is rather large so I was trying to adjust as little as possible in order to get a working product then go back and look for improvements

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you're calling the function twice here:

```
UDP = _does_port_dict_have_type(x)[0]
TCP = _does_port_dict_have_type(x)[1]
```

Since the function returns a tuple, there's no need to call it twice. You can use tuple unpacking and assign both return values in a single statement like:

```
UDP, TCP = _does_port_dict_have_type(x)
```

And your function can be greatly simplified with comprehension:

```
def _does_port_dict_have_type(port_dict):
    tcp = [k for k,v in port_dict.items() if v == "TCP"]
    udp = [k for k,v in port_dict.items() if v == "UDP"]
    return ','.join(udp), ','.join(tcp)
```

In python 2, which it looks like you're using `iteritems` instead of `items`

```
def _does_port_dict_have_type(port_dict):
    tcp = [k for k,v in port_dict.iteritems() if v == "TCP"]
    udp = [k for k,v in port_dict.iteritems() if v == "UDP"]
    return ','.join(udp), ','.join(tcp)
```